# Laravel Yajra-Datatables not showing

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I've been working on a Laravel 8 project and encountered an issue while trying to implement Yajra-Datatables following a tutorial. Unfortunately, I'm facing a problem where the data isn't displaying as expected. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

This is my code:
Controller:

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Voucher::all();
            return DataTables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                    return $actionBtn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view('backend.menu.settings.voucher.list');
    }
```

View:

```
<table id="datatable yajra-datatable" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Type</th>
                                        <th>Value</th>
                                        <th>Start</th>
                                        <th>Expired</th>
                                        <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
                $('#yajra-datatable').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ajax: "{{ route('voucher.index') }}",
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex' },
                        { data: 'code', name: 'code' },
                        { data: 'type', name: 'type' },
                        { data: 'value', name: 'value' },
                        { data: 'start', name: 'start' },
                        { data: 'expired', name: 'expired' },
                        {
                            data: 'action',
                            name: 'action',
                            orderable: true,
                            searchable: true
                        },

                    ]
                });
        });
    </script>
```

I attempted alternative methods and followed different tutorials in my quest to achieve the desired outcome. My expectation was that the data would be displayed correctly as intended.

Comment: First of all: check the devtools of your browser. Any javascript errors? Maybe jquery not loaded? Check the network tab. It should show a network request to the route `voucher.index`. Does it show that network request? Click on it. Does it show json result?

Comment: it said 200 OK for the network status

Answer (score 0):

Your table id property is wrong.

```
<table id="datatable yajra-datatable" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
```

The id should be like this:

```
<table id="yajra-datatable">
```